# what happened in .NET if exception occurred in finalizer method (~Method)

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm curious, what really happens inside `.NET`, if exception happened in finalizer method during garbage collection procedure. Did the logic different for heap and LOH? Could anyone provide detailed description?

Comment: Check this article (section: Finalizers and exceptions): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302312.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it and if it will be no good answers before, will try to answer myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing much special.  The CLR will detect the exception and terminate the program.

Do note that the article linked by @kmatyaszek is grossly outdated.  Swallowing exceptions in finalizers and worker threads was a .NET 1.x feature that caused a lot of misery.  It is pretty difficult to diagnose the reason a program stops behaving properly when this happens.  .NET 2.0 put an end to it, the default policy is to always terminate the program.  Technically that can be overridden by a custom CLR host and the `<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy>` element in the app.exe.config file.  Don't use it unless you like misery.